# Space between inline displayed items

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` object with two Font Awesome icons displayed inline.
What I'd like to achieve is to add more space between the two icons.

This is what it looks like at the moment:

[image: Screenshot of two Font Awesome icons]

This is the relevant HTML:

```
<div id= "contact">
    <i class="fa fa-envelope-o custom1 fa-2x"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-phone custom2 fa-2x"></i>                   
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
div#contact {}

#contact i.fa {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 60px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 12px;
  width: 60px;
  margin-top:60px;
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: add a left and/or right margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing your margin would increase the space between the objects.

```
margin: 10px;
```

If you want to stick with the top and bottom margin, you can use the following piece of CSS:

```
margin: 5px 10px;
```

This will set the top and bottom margin to 5px, and left and right margin to 10px.

Alternatively, you can specify each individually through the following method:

```
margin-top: 5px;
margin-right: 10px;
margin-bottom: 15px;
margin-left: 0px;
```

or

```
margin: 5px 10px 15px 0px;
```

both with the same result.

You can read more about margin here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like the following:

```
.fa {
  margin-right : 1em;
}
```

This will change the margin of the `.fa` class to `1em`, which is size related to the font-size, which allows the user to change how they perceive the website.

Alternatively, the verified answer explains utilizing `px` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Add `margin-right` or `margin-left` to `#contact i.fa`. Check below code.

```css
div#contact {
  background-color: black;
}
#contact i.fa {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 60px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 12px;
  width: 60px;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-left: 60px;
}
#contact i:first-child {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.2/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="contact">
  <i class="fa fa-envelope-o custom1 fa-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-phone custom2 fa-2x"></i>
</div>
```